# fill elements of an array on another array with respecting the size

Tags: javascript

How do I fill elements of an array on another array with respecting the size
Example

```
Arra1 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
Arra2 = ["R","B"]
result = ["R","B","R","B","R"]
```

How can I achieve that

Comment: please clarify this: "with respecting the size"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  with [`modulo %`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder):

```
let Arra1 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
let Arra2 = ["R","B"]
console.log(Arra1.map((num, ind)=>Arra2[ind%Arra2.length]))
//["R","B","R","B","R"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this :

```
r = []
let j = 0
for (let i=0; i<Arra1.length; i++)
{
    if (j>= Arra2.length)
        j = 0
    r.push(Arra2[j])
    j++
}
```

Hope it helps.